What API is related to NSUserTrackingUsageDescription?
Xcode 15.3
When I validate app , it tells that

Invalid purpose string value. The “” value for the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key isn’t allowed in “xxx.app”. Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “xxx.app” bundle should contain a NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.

I  think I never access sensitive user data in my app, so I want to check and make my code clear.
My Podfile just contains

Alamofire

SwiftyStoreKit

Firebase/Analytics


What I want to know is  How can I find where I access user sensitive data ?
What have I tried but failed

First I thought it must be Firebase issue, so I tried to replace it with Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport and set GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS to NO.
I then removed all Firebase references.
clean build folder -> restart xcode -> archive -> validate app

